# Setting Permissions in Shell Scripts Within .tar.gz files Using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I have a .sh script within a folder, and I'm using **Azure DevOps** to generate a tar.gz file that has that shell script.

**Sample Folder Structure**

main_folder/boot.sh

I'm using the `ArchiveFiles@2` task found within Azure DevOps to create that archive, with the following settings:

```yaml
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "main_folder"
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: "tar"
    tarCompression: "gz"
    archiveFile: "$(Build.StagingDirectory)/update.tar.gz
    replaceExistingArchive: true
```

However, after I release this build and extract the tar.gz on my Linux system, when I try to run `boot.sh` it says that permission is denied and I have to use `chmod u=rwx boot.sh` to add the "execute" permission. Is there some way to check how Azure DevOps determines what permissions are added/removed when archiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task ArchiveFiles doesnot change the files permissions while archiving. I tested on my pipeline to archive a .sh file and extract the tar.gz on the linux system. The permissions of .sh file remained the same. So the issue you encountered above might because the origin boot.sh doesnot have the `execute` permission.

You can run the command `ls -l main_folder/boot.sh` to check the file's permission before achiving. And add the permission if it doesnot have `execute` permission.

```
- bash: |
      
   ls -l main_folder/boot.sh  
   chmod u=rwx main_folder/boot.sh

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for checking and letting me know about adding that ability!